# Concurrently path failure

Tags: windows, npm-scripts

## Question Description

I'm trying to simultaneously run multiple commands using the [Concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) package.

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "emojifier",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-dev": "concurrently -c \"yellow.bold,green.bold\" -n \"SERVER,BUILD\" \"./node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev server/index.ts\" \"ng build --watch\" \"ng serve\""
   }
}
```

This script works fine on Ubuntu and Mac. However, when running it via `CMD` or Powershell, I get the error:

```sh
[SERVER] '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[SERVER] operable program or batch file.
[SERVER] ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev server/index.ts exited with code 1
```

Why is this happening and what is a proper work-around? Is this a bug with Concurrently?

## Debugging Attempts

When I switch the forward-slashes to back-slashes:

```sh
concurrently -c "yellow.bold,green.bold" -n "SERVER,BUILD" ".\node_modules\.bin\ts-node-dev.cmd .\server\index.ts" "ng build --watch" "ng serve"
```

The error is resolved.

If I remove the `./` prefix from the path name, the error changes to:

```sh
[SERVER] 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[SERVER] operable program or batch file.
[SERVER] node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev server/index.ts exited with code 1
```

Comment: Sad to see that there seems to be no solution found yet. I have the same problem.